# Socket or WCF when programming twitter like apps?

Tags: messaging

I am going to develop a Twitter-like messaging application on .NET platform, it is going to have almost 500 clients. I wonder that what is the best choice? Socket or WCF?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might be interested in reading the Performance report distributed by Microsoft regarding multiple Distributed Communication Technologies http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx This may give you a good idea about the technology and options you have.

Personally, for a "Twitter-Like" app which you described I would simply go with WCF and depending on the deployment environment you have (do you plan to deploy app on the Internet or locally?) choose an appropriate binding type:

- WSDualHttpBinding
- NetTcpBinding
- NetMsmqBinding
- etc.

There is also a bunch of Blogs on the internet where you can read about WCF perfomrance. Google a bit and make sure to take a look at those (e.g. http://merill.net/2008/10/wcf-performance-optimization-tips/). I think there is no need to go for Socket communication in your case. (You want to send tweets.. short string messages I assume). Concentrate on your App design, WCF will provide the rest.